# Access a storyboard in window.resources from a template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Given the following style, and a storyboard named `animation` that lives in `<Window.Resources>`, how can I pause (and resume) a storyboard triggered from code behind via `((Storyboard)FindResource("animate")).Begin(Tab1, true);`

The following code errors saying the `PauseStoryboard` event can't find animate, which makes sense since it doesn't live in the template.  The `BeginStoryboard` event allows you to bind to resources, but the pause and resume do not.

```
<Style x:Key="HiddenTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Border x:Name="grid">
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>

                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="animate" />
                    </EventTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The animate storyboard:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Storyboard x:Key="animate">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:2.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:5.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I pause (and resume) a storyboard triggered from code behind

First off save the reference to the storyboard which was kicked off in codebehind in a convenient location. Since you now have that as a reference, subscribe to the mouse enter event from the control which you are targeting. Either in Xaml or most likely in codebehind use that reference to the storyboard to pause it.

Thus removing the need to use a style trigger.